# Pattern x:xs with strings

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I am quite new in Haskell world. I was reading the online http://learnyouahaskell.com but I could not understand a small detail about pattern-matching section. I have written those functions

```
myFunc' (firstLetter:_) = firstLetter -- returns firstLetter of given string
```

However if I do something like that

```
myFunc' (firstLetter:_) = "Hello" ++firstLetter
```

Gives me following error when I call this function

```
Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: [[Char]]
        Actual type: [Char]
```

But if I modify the function like this

```
myFunc' (firstLetter:_) = "Hello" ++ [firstLetter]
```

That works fine when I call this function. I was wondering why do I need brackets in other cases. What is actually firstLetter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if you check the type of `(++)` in ghci, you get:

```
Prelude> :t (++)
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

That means it takes two lists of a's as arguments.

Likewise let's see what `(:)` does:

```
Prelude> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

So the first argument of `(:)` need not be a list at all. If we fix `a == Char` we in fact get `(:) :: Char -> String -> String`.

We can define a function `headStr` (recall `String == [Char]`):

```
headStr :: String -> Char
headStr (x:_) = x
headStr _ = error "Empty string!"
```

Note that due to the type of `(:)` in this case `x :: Char`.

On the other hand if we try to define:

```
hello :: String -> String
hello (x:_) = "Hello" ++ x
hello _ = error "Empty string!"
```

it will not type check because in the non error case we get `[Char] ++ Char`. As ghci helpfully told us, the second argument to `(++)` must always be a list and in this case since the first argument is `[Char]` it must also be `[Char]`.

As you noticed yourself, this can be fixed by wrapping `x` in a list:

```
hello' :: String -> String
hello' (x:_) = "Hello" ++ [x]
hello' _ = error "Empty string!"
```

and this works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

```
"Hello ++ firstLetter
```

The types there are:

```
[Char] ++ Char
```

As you can see, that isn't possible. You can't add a `Char` to a `[Char]`, they are different types!

But by doing

```
[firstLetter]
```

you are creating a list with 1 element, `firstLetter`. Because `firstLetter` is a `Char`, you'll get a list of `Char`s, i.e. the list is of type `[Char]`.

Adding 2 lists of the same type is allowed, and that's why it works in the second case.

Comment: Hi Rakete1111, thanks for your comment. I just had another small experiment to confirm one more thing. You mentioned that I can't add [Char] to char. However, when I do this line in ghci ( 'c':"dfg" ) it is valid. So can we say (++) operator requires same type.

Comment: @CanEldem Well, technically, yes. You're line is valid because the type of `c` is the type of an element in `"dfg"`, i.e. `Char`. `"c":"dfg"` would be invalid.